# Runtime visibility of classes between bundles in RCP application

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp

**Summary:**
I'm having trouble with my OSGi bundles seeing classes made available at runtime in the OSGi environment.

**Context:**
My RCP application stores objects to disk which involves storing the class name of each object. The idea is when loaded, objects will be reinstantiated using the class names that were written to disk. The main `AppBundle` performs the storage operation. Among the objects stored are objects of types supplied by other bundles, e.g., `Bundle1` and `Bundle2`.

**Problem:**
When I try to read class information based on the stored name, although the same bundles and their provided classes are in the OSGi runtime, the class information is not visible from my `AppBundle`. I've included a schematic of the code that handles the storage and reading.

```
public class Storage{
    transient Object[] objs = new Object[3];

    {
        // Something link the following happens dynamically during the application
        objs[0] = new AppBundleClass();
        objs[1] = new Bundle1Class();
        objs[2] = new Bundle2Class();
    }

    // Persisted to disk
    private String[] objTypes;

    public void saveToDisk(){
        objTypes = new String[objs.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < objTypes.length; i++)
            objTypes[i] = objs[i].getClass().getCanonicalName();
    }

    public void afterLoadingFromDisk(){
        objs = new Object[objTypes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++){
            Class<?> klass = Class.forName(objTypes[i]);
            // **** Throws error above ****

            objs = loadByClass(klass);      
            // Custom method that works for classes withing the app.
        }
    }
}
```

`AppBundle` does not have a build dependency on `Bundle1` or `Bundle2`. The idea is that the user of the application can activate different bundles at runtime as they need.

**Attempted Solutions:**
I'm suspecting that the problem has to do with OSGi's use of different classloaders for each bundle and the classloader for `AppBundle` not being able to resolve `Bundle1Class` because it is not a compile-time dependency specified either via bundle-dependencies or package imports. So, I tried the following.

```
Bundle1/MANIFEST.MF
   DynamicImport-Package: *
   (to allow packages from this bundle to be dynamically visible)

AppBundle/MANIFEST.MF
    Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: global
    (to allow this bundle to be able to resolve any class available in the OSGi runtime)
```

**Expected behavior:**
The classes from `Bundle1` and `Bundle2` should now be visible to `AppBundle`.

**Actual behavior:**
Oddly, every now and then (quite randomly), this works. However, most of the time, I run into errors regarding the class not being found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need BuddyPolicy. Simply make sure Bundle1 and Bundle2 export the packages and AppBundle has `DynamicImport-Package: *`.

Keep in mind though that this approach only works if every such package is only exported by one bundle. In general identifying a class just by class name is a flawed approach in OSGi.

A better approach would be to let each bundle handle the classes it knows and do the serialization itself. This would also better match module boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm needing to do all this to maintain some backward compatibility while we transition out from a completely non-modular design.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Christian that identifying a class purely by name is the root of the problem, but would offer a different solution.

In any modular environment, a class name is not sufficient to identify a class because the same name could be known to multiple bundles. Your application is currently saving data with only class name attached, so just change this to save both classname and bundle ID where the bundle identity consists of `Bundle-SymbolicName` and `Bundle-Version`.

When loading, use the `Bundle-SymbolicName` and `Bundle-Version` to find a matching `Bundle` object and then invoke `Bundle.loadClass(..)` to load the class by name.

You do not need to export the package containing the persisted classes or import this package into your persistence framework bundle.

Comment: I agree with the class name along being a problem. Do you know of any Java-based serialization libraries that would work with bundle-names and versions? Currently, we are relying on Kryo, which (I think) only uses the class name for this type of storage.